# How write onfocus and onblur events for @Html.Editor()?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to create a search field. My code so far:

```
<input type="text" value="Search" onfocus="if (this.value=='Search') 
{this.value='';}"  onblur="if (this.value=='') {this.value='Search';}" 
class="textbox"/>
```

I want to change the `<input>` tag to `@Html.Editor("term").`

How can I write the onfocus and onblur events using `@Html.Editor("term")?`

Comment: @Html.Editor("term") sends "term" text to Search action in controller.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC then? You should add that as a tag.

Comment: <form action="@Url.Action( "Search", "Home" )" enctype="text/plain" method="get">
<input type="text" value="Search" onfocus="if (this.value=='Search') {this.value='';}" onblur="if (this.value=='') {this.value='Search';}" class="textbox" />
<input class="icon" type="image" src="images/searchicon.png" )"
</form>

Comment: I changed this to:

 @using ( Html.BeginForm( "Search", "Home", FormMethod.Get ) )
{ 
  @Html.Editor( "term")
<div>
<input class="icon" type="image" src="@Url.Content( "~/images/searchicon.png" )" />
</div>
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use HTML5 `placeholder` attribute it does the same thing

Replace -

```
<input type="text" value="Search" onfocus="if (this.value=='Search') 
{this.value='';}"  onblur="if (this.value=='') {this.value='Search';}" 
class="textbox"/>
```

With

```
<input type="text" class="textbox" placeholder="Search" />
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uCkef/1/

Here is how you can make `'placeholder'` attribute work in IE browsers - 
http://dipaksblogonline.blogspot.in/2012/02/html5-placeholder-in-ie7-and-ie8-fixed.html

And for focus and blur events -

```
$('input').focus(function(){
   console.log('focused');
}).blur(function(){
   console.log('blured');
})
```

Comment: Firstly, I could not use this, that is why changed code. If I want use my old <form> tag. ho to make <form> send "term" text to Search action? what is wrong?

Comment: **<form action="@Url.Action( "Search", "Home" )" enctype="text/plain" method="get">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="textbox" /> <input class="icon" type="image" src="images/searchicon.png" )" </form>**   

it doesnt send query to action

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean "to Accept" ?

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the javascript as a new html attrebute

```
@HTML.TextboxFor(m => m.term, new { onfocus="if (this.value=='Search') {this.value='';}" })
```